# How to create a fixed dialog box with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

It easier to give you a well know example:

If you are logged in with Google, then you can click on the top right profile icon, then there appears a kinda dialog box. How can I do a similar thing? It is probably made with jQuery, I guess. The closes thing I found is that you create a div with toggle function, but it is not the best, cause it pushes down the whole page content.

And it doesn't seem to be a simple javascript prompt neither... (but I am not that experienced to be able to judge it...)

Do you know how to create such a thing? Thank you!!

Comment: You could use jquery UI. Under the tab download you are able to choose which elements you want to use. Also what you described in your question. The div with toggle. Put some css on it like: `position: fixed; z-index: 10;` to prevent the push down

Comment: https://jqueryui.com/dialog/

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you're looking for but if you use CSS positioning, you can avoid the pushdown, use position:absolute and position:relative

Comment: but I have some concerns about fixed positions, cause if the user zooms in or out that may be a problem then, isn't it?

Comment: @user3435407 there are other posibilitys than fixed. If you use chrome to test your site. Right click the element to expect. Then you can also fiddle around witth your css. Chrome also helps you, if you would delete the value behind `position:` then chrome will give some options

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simple example of how to do it with jQuery.

```js
$('.button').on('click', function() {
  $('.hoverelement').toggle();
});
```

```css
.hoverelement {
  display: none;
  border: solid 1px;
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 200px;
  text-align: left;
  position: relative;
  top: 10px;
  z-index: 10;
}
.container {
  position: absolute;
}
.othercontent {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  z-index: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="button">Button</div>
  <div class="hoverelement">
    <h1>your content here</h1>
    <p>put some content here</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="othercontent">
  other content
  <br />other content
  <br />other content
  <br />other content
  <br />other content
  <br />other content
  <br />other content
  <br />other content
  <br />other content
  <br />other content
  <br />other content
  <br />other content
  <br />other content
  <br />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this and put profile image

```js
$('img').on('click', function() {
  $('.hoverelement').toggle();
});
```

```css
.hoverelement {
  display: none;
  border: solid 1px;
  width: 200px;
  text-align: left;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 999;
  top: 100px;
}
.container {
  position: relative;
  top: 45px;
  float: right;
  text-align: right;
}
img {
   width: 100px;
    
      }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/33/Vanamo_Logo.png" alt=""/>
  <div class="hoverelement">
    <h1>your content here</h1>
    <p>put some content here</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First when the user click on some icon, you should get it's coordinates `left,top` i'm not sure but you can do it using `$icon.offset()`

now you have left and top of the dialog you can do :

```
var $dialog_div = $("<div></div>"); //make new item

// make sure it floats and not pushing other contents of the pge 
$dialog_div.css("position","absolute"); 

$dialog_div.css("z-index","9999"); // or some big number to be above all content
$dialog_div.css("left",left); // the left you got from icon offset
$dialog_div.css("top",top); // the top you got from icon offset

/////// append some content to the dialog and add some css classes 


$("body").append($dialog_div); //finally append it to the body
```

i hove that helps to make the dialog you want.

but it's better to use some library like `jqueryUi` or `Bootstrap` or something